# How to serve an image in django without using <img> tag in django?

Tags: html, django, image, django-templates

Recently I started learning Django and at the first actually I want to prepare an API in order to serve images.
for this purpose, when anybody requests to access to an image, my program should read raw image data from local library and serve it and prepare an access to this image for anybody who requests that image.

notice that i don't want to show image with  tag in my html file. just prepare an access to raw data in order to manipulation that image or anything similar.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear as it stands. I'm not at all sure what "just prepare an access to raw data in order to manipulation that image or anything similar." actually means. Could you maybe provide an example of what you would like?

Comment: @urbanespaceman You are right, maybe my question was a little unclear. assume that we have a local directory and i want to write a program in order to serve these images, so everybody can requests for a specific image and in response, my program give it raw data of that image so he(or she) can display, edit, manupulate or ...  on it.

Comment: In what format will this raw data be provided? Is it a photogtaph .RAW file? Something else? Please be specific.

Comment: @urbanespaceman It is just a simple jpeg format file. i want prepare an API to access this image in order to change raw data of each image before displaying it.

Comment: I think you should be able to just read the file as a binary file if that's all you need. Alternatively look at using `pillow` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a view that opens the image in 'rb' mode and reads it, and returns the image in text or text/html mode via a HttpResponse.

Note: The image path you are returning cannot be a remote path, it has to be a file inside your server, that can be accessed by your views.py file.

You will need to give back the response via HttpResponse (from django.http) and cannot use render() to return the response, in this case.

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
    with open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'static', 'delete.jpg'), rb) as f:
        image_data = f.read()
    return HttpResponse(image_data, content_type="text")
```

Comment: Noted @SamuelPhilipp.